# Amazon EC2 nginx php issues

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

We are moving a file from godaddy hosting to AWS.

I created an Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instance and MySQL RDS and successfully moved the files.

I made changes to the database configuration and configured my hosts file as per nginx.

My question is

1) When I put in the public IP address(Elastic IP) it is routing to the site that is hosted in godaddy. However if I make changes to wp-config.php database settings, they are getting reflected and it is pointing to AWS. Did anyone else run into the same issue.

So when I run into any issues it points to the IP of AWS, however if everything is fine it points to the IP of GoDaddy.

One thing  I have to mention here though is that the domain and the site are still being hosted in godaddy.

The nginx conf file looks like the following

```
server {

listen 80;

server_name _;

root /var/www/example.com/public_html/;

index index.php index.html;

access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/domain-error.log;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.php index.html;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

I havent hardcoded any IP's in the hosts file as it just has default values.

Here is the /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: there are some confusing contradictory statements there, however, you have in some site config file with hard coded IP's fix that

Comment: Sorry for that, but the issue itself is confusing. I have put in my site config file and hosts file here. Is there any other place that I need to check, as I havent hardcoded that anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with wordpress. Wordpress has a table called wp_options. I had to change the values of siteUrl and home and then it stopped routing.